# how do disable Gzipping

Tags: c#, .net-core, gzip

I'm having an issue with the game launcher I'm making where my line that downloads a zip

```
webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=15m02YGWX0Uo1NQobt_iQ8IDfjK-7dvWl"), GameZip, _version);
```

Is downloading just fine for the most part, but I run into an issue with it be a Gzipped file instead of a standard zip file, any fix for this? It's making my launcher unable to unzip the file which it needs to do

Comment: gzip is a lot more "standard" than zip. [This page](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/performance) explains how to set your headers and user agent to tell Google Drive to use gzip. Maybe ensuring you're not doing those things will prevent it.

Comment: I'm not doing any of that, I just got the one line to download it and the other code related to it is attempting to unzip the file

Comment: Some of those settings might be the defaults. I'm suggesting that you explicitly do the opposite of what that page says.

Answer (score 0):

C# Download Public File From Google Drive™ (works for large files as well)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;

/* EXAMPLE USAGE
    FileDownloader fileDownloader = new FileDownloader();
    // This callback is triggered for DownloadFileAsync only
    fileDownloader.DownloadProgressChanged += ( sender, e ) => Console.WriteLine( "Progress changed " + e.BytesReceived + " " + e.TotalBytesToReceive );
    // This callback is triggered for both DownloadFile and DownloadFileAsync
    fileDownloader.DownloadFileCompleted += ( sender, e ) => Console.WriteLine( "Download completed" );
    fileDownloader.DownloadFileAsync( "https://INSERT_DOWNLOAD_LINK_HERE", @"C:\downloadedFile.txt" );
*/
public class FileDownloader : IDisposable
{
    private const string GOOGLE_DRIVE_DOMAIN = "drive.google.com";
    private const string GOOGLE_DRIVE_DOMAIN2 = "https://drive.google.com";

    // In the worst case, it is necessary to send 3 download requests to the Drive address
    //   1. an NID cookie is returned instead of a download_warning cookie
    //   2. download_warning cookie returned
    //   3. the actual file is downloaded
    private const int GOOGLE_DRIVE_MAX_DOWNLOAD_ATTEMPT = 3;

    public delegate void DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler( object sender, DownloadProgress progress );

    // Custom download progress reporting (needed for Google Drive)
    public class DownloadProgress
    {
        public long BytesReceived, TotalBytesToReceive;
        public object UserState;

        public int ProgressPercentage
        {
            get
            {
                if( TotalBytesToReceive > 0L )
                    return (int) ( ( (double) BytesReceived / TotalBytesToReceive ) * 100 );

                return 0;
            }
        }
    }

    // Web client that preserves cookies (needed for Google Drive)
    private class CookieAwareWebClient : WebClient
    {
        private class CookieContainer
        {
            private readonly Dictionary<string, string> cookies = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            public string this[Uri address]
            {
                get
                {
                    string cookie;
                    if( cookies.TryGetValue( address.Host, out cookie ) )
                        return cookie;

                    return null;
                }
                set
                {
                    cookies[address.Host] = value;
                }
            }
        }

        private readonly CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();
        public DownloadProgress ContentRangeTarget;

        protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest( Uri address )
        {
            WebRequest request = base.GetWebRequest( address );
            if( request is HttpWebRequest )
            {
                string cookie = cookies[address];
                if( cookie != null )
                    ( (HttpWebRequest) request ).Headers.Set( "cookie", cookie );

                if( ContentRangeTarget != null )
                    ( (HttpWebRequest) request ).AddRange( 0 );
            }

            return request;
        }

        protected override WebResponse GetWebResponse( WebRequest request, IAsyncResult result )
        {
            return ProcessResponse( base.GetWebResponse( request, result ) );
        }

        protected override WebResponse GetWebResponse( WebRequest request )
        {
            return ProcessResponse( base.GetWebResponse( request ) );
        }

        private WebResponse ProcessResponse( WebResponse response )
        {
            string[] cookies = response.Headers.GetValues( "Set-Cookie" );
            if( cookies != null && cookies.Length > 0 )
            {
                int length = 0;
                for( int i = 0; i < cookies.Length; i++ )
                    length += cookies[i].Length;

                StringBuilder cookie = new StringBuilder( length );
                for( int i = 0; i < cookies.Length; i++ )
                    cookie.Append( cookies[i] );

                this.cookies[response.ResponseUri] = cookie.ToString();
            }

            if( ContentRangeTarget != null )
            {
                string[] rangeLengthHeader = response.Headers.GetValues( "Content-Range" );
                if( rangeLengthHeader != null && rangeLengthHeader.Length > 0 )
                {
                    int splitIndex = rangeLengthHeader[0].LastIndexOf( '/' );
                    if( splitIndex >= 0 && splitIndex < rangeLengthHeader[0].Length - 1 )
                    {
                        long length;
                        if( long.TryParse( rangeLengthHeader[0].Substring( splitIndex + 1 ), out length ) )
                            ContentRangeTarget.TotalBytesToReceive = length;
                    }
                }
            }

            return response;
        }
    }

    private readonly CookieAwareWebClient webClient;
    private readonly DownloadProgress downloadProgress;

    private Uri downloadAddress;
    private string downloadPath;

    private bool asyncDownload;
    private object userToken;

    private bool downloadingDriveFile;
    private int driveDownloadAttempt;

    public event DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler DownloadProgressChanged;
    public event AsyncCompletedEventHandler DownloadFileCompleted;

    public FileDownloader()
    {
        webClient = new CookieAwareWebClient();
        webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += DownloadProgressChangedCallback;
        webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += DownloadFileCompletedCallback;

        downloadProgress = new DownloadProgress();
    }

    public void DownloadFile( string address, string fileName )
    {
        DownloadFile( address, fileName, false, null );
    }

    public void DownloadFileAsync( string address, string fileName, object userToken = null )
    {
        DownloadFile( address, fileName, true, userToken );
    }

    private void DownloadFile( string address, string fileName, bool asyncDownload, object userToken )
    {
        downloadingDriveFile = address.StartsWith( GOOGLE_DRIVE_DOMAIN ) || address.StartsWith( GOOGLE_DRIVE_DOMAIN2 );
        if( downloadingDriveFile )
        {
            address = GetGoogleDriveDownloadAddress( address );
            driveDownloadAttempt = 1;

            webClient.ContentRangeTarget = downloadProgress;
        }
        else
            webClient.ContentRangeTarget = null;

        downloadAddress = new Uri( address );
        downloadPath = fileName;

        downloadProgress.TotalBytesToReceive = -1L;
        downloadProgress.UserState = userToken;

        this.asyncDownload = asyncDownload;
        this.userToken = userToken;

        DownloadFileInternal();
    }

    private void DownloadFileInternal()
    {
        if( !asyncDownload )
        {
            webClient.DownloadFile( downloadAddress, downloadPath );

            // This callback isn't triggered for synchronous downloads, manually trigger it
            DownloadFileCompletedCallback( webClient, new AsyncCompletedEventArgs( null, false, null ) );
        }
        else if( userToken == null )
            webClient.DownloadFileAsync( downloadAddress, downloadPath );
        else
            webClient.DownloadFileAsync( downloadAddress, downloadPath, userToken );
    }

    private void DownloadProgressChangedCallback( object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e )
    {
        if( DownloadProgressChanged != null )
        {
            downloadProgress.BytesReceived = e.BytesReceived;
            if( e.TotalBytesToReceive > 0L )
                downloadProgress.TotalBytesToReceive = e.TotalBytesToReceive;

            DownloadProgressChanged( this, downloadProgress );
        }
    }

    private void DownloadFileCompletedCallback( object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e )
    {
        if( !downloadingDriveFile )
        {
            if( DownloadFileCompleted != null )
                DownloadFileCompleted( this, e );
        }
        else
        {
            if( driveDownloadAttempt < GOOGLE_DRIVE_MAX_DOWNLOAD_ATTEMPT && !ProcessDriveDownload() )
            {
                // Try downloading the Drive file again
                driveDownloadAttempt++;
                DownloadFileInternal();
            }
            else if( DownloadFileCompleted != null )
                DownloadFileCompleted( this, e );
        }
    }

    // Downloading large files from Google Drive prompts a warning screen and requires manual confirmation
    // Consider that case and try to confirm the download automatically if warning prompt occurs
    // Returns true, if no more download requests are necessary
    private bool ProcessDriveDownload()
    {
        FileInfo downloadedFile = new FileInfo( downloadPath );
        if( downloadedFile == null )
            return true;

        // Confirmation page is around 50KB, shouldn't be larger than 60KB
        if( downloadedFile.Length > 60000L )
            return true;

        // Downloaded file might be the confirmation page, check it
        string content;
        using( var reader = downloadedFile.OpenText() )
        {
            // Confirmation page starts with <!DOCTYPE html>, which can be preceeded by a newline
            char[] header = new char[20];
            int readCount = reader.ReadBlock( header, 0, 20 );
            if( readCount < 20 || !( new string( header ).Contains( "<!DOCTYPE html>" ) ) )
                return true;

            content = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        int linkIndex = content.LastIndexOf( "href=\"/uc?" );
        if( linkIndex < 0 )
            return true;

        linkIndex += 6;
        int linkEnd = content.IndexOf( '"', linkIndex );
        if( linkEnd < 0 )
            return true;

        downloadAddress = new Uri( "https://drive.google.com" + content.Substring( linkIndex, linkEnd - linkIndex ).Replace( "&amp;", "&" ) );
        return false;
    }

    // Handles the following formats (links can be preceeded by https://):
    // - drive.google.com/open?id=FILEID
    // - drive.google.com/file/d/FILEID/view?usp=sharing
    // - drive.google.com/uc?id=FILEID&export=download
    private string GetGoogleDriveDownloadAddress( string address )
    {
        int index = address.IndexOf( "id=" );
        int closingIndex;
        if( index > 0 )
        {
            index += 3;
            closingIndex = address.IndexOf( '&', index );
            if( closingIndex < 0 )
                closingIndex = address.Length;
        }
        else
        {
            index = address.IndexOf( "file/d/" );
            if( index < 0 ) // address is not in any of the supported forms
                return string.Empty;

            index += 7;

            closingIndex = address.IndexOf( '/', index );
            if( closingIndex < 0 )
            {
                closingIndex = address.IndexOf( '?', index );
                if( closingIndex < 0 )
                    closingIndex = address.Length;
            }
        }

        return string.Concat( "https://drive.google.com/uc?id=", address.Substring( index, closingIndex - index ), "&export=download" );
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        webClient.Dispose();
    }
}
```

**How To**

```
// NOTE: FileDownloader is IDisposable!
FileDownloader fileDownloader = new FileDownloader();

// This callback is triggered for DownloadFileAsync only
fileDownloader.DownloadProgressChanged += ( sender, e ) => Console.WriteLine( "Progress changed " + e.BytesReceived + " " + e.TotalBytesToReceive );
// This callback is triggered for both DownloadFile and DownloadFileAsync
fileDownloader.DownloadFileCompleted += ( sender, e ) => Console.WriteLine( "Download completed" );

fileDownloader.DownloadFileAsync( "https://INSERT_DOWNLOAD_LINK_HERE", @"C:\downloadedFile.txt" );
```

references:

https://gist.github.com/yasirkula/d0ec0c07b138748e5feaecbd93b6223c
https://www.daimto.com/download-files-from-google-drive-with-c/